# Git clone pull authentication

Tags: git, clone

I ve just changed PC, i installed git bash as always. And i got some wird problem.
When i always was doing some git pull or git clone http:// link/repo.git everything worked fine. Atm i cant pull or clone because:

**$ git pull origin master or git clone http:// link/repo.git:**

fatal: could not read Username for 'http:// link': No such file or directory

When i use this command from old PC everything works. I type my username then password, now it even not allow me to do that.

**FIXED**, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be Aware, thats bug of git 1.8.5. Just downgrade to 1.8.4 it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following format

```
git clone username@domain.com:repo-name.git
```

One more thing. Is your new PC SSH key added for repo authentication ?

Comment: not needed, i am using http.
it work only when i use:

git clone username:password@domain.com:repo-name.git

With only username he cant find password. that solve problem with clone, but i use many command that uses username and password and it is problematic to use such expression always

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that setting up a global username in git could help:

```
git config --global user.name "Billy Everyteen"
```